# Java passing data between two classes

Tags: java, generics

I have a very stupid and elementary questions, however I can't seem to get around it. I am trying to pass data between 3 classes, so this is the approach I took:

Class A

```
public class GroupChat {

    public String message;
    public String myId;
    public String otherID;

    public GroupChat() {

    }

    public String getOtherID() {
        return otherID;
    }

    public void setOtherID(String otherID) {
        this.otherID = otherID;
    }

    public String getMyId() {
        return myId;
    }

    public void setMyId(String myId) {
        this.myId = myId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Class B - which generates the data on button click

```
GroupChat chat = new GroupChat();
chat.setParticipants(participants);
chat.setMyId(userId);
chat.setOtherID(id);
chat.setMessage(message);
```

When I print out the log of these variables in the GroupChat class, all is perfect.

However, when I attempt to use the getters to get data to class C, which is where I need them, they are returning a null value.

Class C

```
GroupChat chat = new GroupChat();
chat.getMessage(),
chat.getItemView(),
chat.getMyId(),
chat.getOtherID());
```

I even tried to log the data in the GroupChat class. When I enter the data, using the setters, everything is fine, however when logging the data on the getters, these are returning null. There must be something in the GroupChat class which is nullifying the variables.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?
Thanks a million.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same instance of `GroupChat`?  If you use `new` in both places, you are dealing with two different instances.  Setting values on one will not affect the other.

Comment: I believe you will need to set the values in Class C or pass around your GroupChat object.

Comment: ahaaaa, so what do I need to do to have the same instance of GroupChat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you call:

```
GroupChat chat = new GroupChat();
```

you are creating new object with default values (e.g. 0, nulls).

If you want to use your object "B" you have to return it from the function where you call setters.

E.g.

```
public GroupChat getDataAfterButtonPress() {
    GroupChat chat = new GroupChat();
    chat.setParticipants(participants);
    chat.setMyId(userId);
    chat.setOtherID(id);
    chat.setMessage(message);
    return chat;
}
```

Then, you can use this object later in your code:

```
GroupChat result = getDataAfterButtonPress();
```

Comment: But how can I pass getDataAfterButtonPress() to another class?

Comment: To answer this one, I need more details on the architecture. But, I guess, it's just enough to return/pass GroupChat from Listener that is called whenever user presses the button.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to conclude without full code.  The only problem I can see is that you use different instances in both case.  When in class C, you create a new GroupChat instead of passing the one you create in class B.

Comment: How can I use the same instance?

Comment: In class C add a setter or a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Make sure you don't reuse new.  You can do new ClassC(existingInstance) or new ClassC.setChat(existingInstance).